# Problem occurred in running the abe explorer for public blockchain running locally

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, altcoin, peercoin, abe

i have my own blockchain working locally i need to run an abe explorer for the same but i encountered with the problem while running the last command where saiyan is my blockchain name

> python -m Peercoin-Abe.abe --config /home/explorer/saiyan_abe.conf --commit-bytes 100000 --no-serve
>   test
>
> RPC data not understood: block hash mismatch
>
> catch_up_rpc: abort
>
> Skipping datadir /home/explorer/.digitalcarbon: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/explorer/.digitalcarbon/blocks/blk00000.dat'

how do i remove this problem it is urgent please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks